# Proof time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, proof

I'm trying to determine the complexity of this two functions, where D in an integer and list is a list of integers:

```
def solve(D, list):
    for element in List:
      doFunc(element, D, list)

def doFunc(element, D, list):
  quantityx = 0 
  if(D > 0):
    for otherElement in list:
      if otherElement == element:
        quantityx += 1
    return quantityx + (doFunc ((element+1), (D-1), list))
  return 0
```

Intuitively, I think it has a O(n²) where n is the quantity of elements of list, but I'd like to proof it in a formal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observation: `solve` calls `doFunc`, but not the other way around. Therefore, the complexity of `solve` will depend on the complexity of `doFunc`, but not the other way around. We need to figure out the complexity of `doFunc` first.

Let `T(E, D, N)` be the time complexity of `doFunc` as a function of `E`, `D` and the number of elements `N` in the list. Every time `doFunc` is called, we do `N` iterations of the loop and then invoke `doFunc` with `E+1`, `D-1`, and the list unchanged. Based on this, we know that the time complexity of `doFunc` is given by the following recursive formula:

`T(E, D, N) = aN + b + T(E+1, D-1, N)`

Here, `a` and `b` are some constants to be determined.

Now we need a base case for this recursive formula. Our base case, the only time we don't recurse, is when `D <= 0`. Assuming that `D` is non-negative, this means `D = 0` is the base case. We get the following additional requirement:

`T(E, 0, N) = c`

Here, `c` is some constant to be determined.

Putting this all together, we can list out a few values for different values of `D` and see if we can identify a pattern:

```
D    T(E, D, N)
0    c
1    c + b + aN
2    c + 2b + 2aN
3    c + 3b + 3aN
...
k    c + kb + kaN
```

Based on this, we can guess that `T(E, D, N) = c + Db + aDN` for some constants `a, b, c`. We can see that this formula satisfies the base case and we can check that it also satisfies the recursive part (try this). Therefore, this is our function.

Assuming `E`, `D` and `N` are all independent and vary freely, the time complexity of `doFunc` is best rendered as `O(c + Db + aDN) = O(DN)`.

Since `solve` calls `doFunc` once for each element in the list, its complexity is simply `N` times that of `doFunc`, i.e., `O(DN^2)`.